# Retrieve Image Source with XPath in R using XML-Package

Tags: r, xpath

I'd like to retrieve the image source within the below HTML code block, but can't find the right syntax.

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
script <- getURL("http://www.floraweb.de/pflanzenarten/druck.xsql?suchnr=4346")
(doc <- htmlParse(script))


<div class="divider"><hr></div>
<div id="contentblock"><div id="content">
<h1>Alle Angaben</h1>
<p>Zu der von Ihnen gewÃ¤hlten Pflanzenart liegen folgende Informationen vor:</p>
<p><a href="../glossar.html#bname">Wissenschaftlicher Name</a>:Â Poa badensis agg. </p>
<p><a href="../glossar.html#bdeu">Deutscher Name</a>:Â Artengruppe Badener Rispengras</p>
<p><a href="../glossar.html#bfam">FamilienzugehÃ¶rigkeit</a>: Poaceae, SÃ¼ÃŸgrÃ¤ser</p>
<p><a href="../glossar.html#bsta">Status</a>:Â keine AngabenÂ </p>
<p class="centeredcontent"><img border="0" src="../bilder/Arten/dummy.tmb.jpg"></p>
```

Desired result:
"../bilder/Arten/dummy.tmb.jpg"

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
script <- getURL("http://www.floraweb.de/pflanzenarten/druck.xsql?suchnr=4346")
doc <- htmlTreeParse(script,useInternalNodes=T)
img<-xpathSApply(doc,'//*/p[@class="centeredcontent"]/img',xmlAttrs)
> img[2]
[1] "../bilder/Arten/dummy.tmb.jpg"
```

The use of Internal representation maybe necessary

EDIT:

I just looked up `htmlParse` and its equivalent to `htmlTreeParse(useInternalNodes=T)`

@Martin Morgan thanks have added below

```
doc <- htmlParse("http://www.floraweb.de/pflanzenarten/druck.xsql?suchnr=4346")
xpathSApply(doc, '//*/p[@class="centeredcontent"]/img/@src')
```

Comment: Two more efficient things to do -- no need to use getURL, just `htmlParse("http://www.floraweb.de/pflanzenarten/druck.xsql?suchnr=4346")`; query the attribute in xpath, so `xpathSApply(doc, "//img/@src")`.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
//div[@id='contentblock']
   /div/p[@class='centeredcontent']
         /img/@src
```

This selects the `src` attribute of any `p` element whose `class` attribute has the value `"centeredcontent"`and that (the `p` element) is a child of a `div` that is a child of a `div` whose `id` attribute has the value '"contentblock"'.

**If you want to get directly the value of this attribute, use**:

```
string(//div[@id='contentblock']
         /div/p[@class='centeredcontent']
              /img/@src)
```